# How to run a function onClick with different values from PHP <li>'s?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to scan through my Media dir and create a list with it. 
Then I want to create a  TAG with the name and the source of the files in the dir. 
Unfortunately I cannot pass the name (argument) to the function.
(I'm replacing "." and space to pass the whole word)

So here is my code:

```
<div id="play">
</div>
<ul>
<?php
$files = scandir('media');
$anzahl=count($files);
for($i=2;$i<$anzahl;$i++){
  $temp_file = $files[$i];
  $front = str_replace(" ","_",$temp_file);
  $back = str_replace(".","Ó",$front);
  echo "<li onclick='video_tag($back)'>".$temp_file."</li>";
}

?>
</ul>
<script>
  function video_tag(x){
    console.log(x);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: have you tried `echo "<li onclick='video_tag(\'".$back."\')'>".$temp_file."</li>";` ?

Comment: view the source of what is generated, I am sure you will see the problem.

Comment: Yes, doesnt change anyhing - the error message is: Uncaught ReferenceError: richtextÓrtf is not defined at HTMLLIElement.onclick. I found out that you shouldnt do onClick - instead use DOM but this wouldnt work for different names from different files

Comment: <div id="play">
</div>
<ul>
<li onclick='video_tag(powerpointÓpptx)'>powerpoint.pptx</li><li onclick='video_tag(richtextÓrtf)'>richtext.rtf</li></ul>
<script>
  function video_tag(x){
    console.log(x);
  }
</script>

Comment: And can clearly see missing quotes around the string you are trying to pass into the function. So javascript interprets it as a variable...which is undefined

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input @charlietfl

Comment: Based on what generated source?

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape the `$back` like: `"<li onclick='video_tag("'.$back.'")'>".$temp_file."</li>"` otherwise it won't recognize `$back` as a variable in PHP.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input - tried that already

Comment: Hi. @Mark_Ed code should be "<li onclick=\"video_tag('".$back."')\">".$temp_file."</li>"

Comment: Yeah @ankabout I just noticed -,- rookie mistake haha, was going to change it.

Answer (score 0):

Or HTML way ?

```js
function video_tag(t,x){
  if(this.event) // IE, Chrome
    console.log(event.srcElement.innerText, x);
  else // FF
    console.log(t.innerText, x);
}
```

```html
<div id="play">
</div>
<ul>
<li onclick='video_tag(this,1)'>Text of 1</li>
<li onclick='video_tag(this,2)'>Text of 2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Firefox version should be easier if you pass also this, you can accept some of answers under voting button if you want. Or vote up on some, but better not down ;-)